# integrating zurb motion-ui in a simple html, css javascript project

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

How can I integrate [zurb motion-ui](https://github.com/zurb/motion-ui) in a simple html, css javascript project. I would wish to use the animations but from the [documentation](https://github.com/zurb/motion-ui/tree/master/docs) there is no clear directions on how to include it in a simple project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not familiar with SASS, NPM/Bower you can download **Motion UI Starter Kit** from official page http://zurb.com/playground/motion-ui which is really easy to understand.

**Super easy example** could looks like this one:

1. Include CSS `motion-ui.min.css`
2. Include JS `motion-ui.min.js`
3. Write some simple javascript for *onclick* animation

**What does it do?**

When you click on the link (`.js-button`) image (`.js-image`) will do rotating animation (`spin-in`)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="motion-ui.min.css" />
    <title>Motion UI Super Simple Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" class="js-button">Click to animate!</a>
    <br /><br />
    <img src="http://satyr.io/200" class="js-image" />


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="motion-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var element = $('.js-image');           
        var button = $('.js-button');

        button.click(function() {
            MotionUI.animateIn(element, 'spin-in');
        });     
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```